# Structuremap - Override registration

Tags: c#, dependencies, registry, structuremap, code-injection

Is it possible to register an interface in a registry, then "re-register" it to override the first registration?

I.E.:

```
For<ISomeInterface>().Use<SomeClass>();
For<ISomeInterface>().Use<SomeClassExtension>();
```

What I want here on runtime is that my object factory returns `SomeClassExtension` when I ask for `ISomeInterface`.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Good news, I found out that yes. It all depends on the order that the registry rules are added to the object factory container. So if you are using multiple registry classes as I was doing, you need to find a way to give a priority to add them to the container.

In other words, instead of using the `.LookForRegistries()` which gets all the `Registry` classes in the wrong order, try to find all the `Registry` files, set them in the order you want and add them manually to the object factory container:

```
    ObjectFactory.Container.Configure(x => x.AddRegistry(registry));
```

That way, you have full control on what rules you want.

Hope it helps :)

Answer (score 2):

I just wanted to add my solution to the problem when I needed to override some parts of a registry in my SpecFlow test.

I did find this thread pretty early in my search, but it didn´t really help me find the solution, so I hope it will help you.

My problem was that the "DataContext" in "StoreRegistry" (used by the application) use the "HybridHttpOrThreadLocalScoped" and I needed it to be "Transient" in my tests.

```
The code looked like this:
[Binding]
public class MySpecFlowContext
{    
...
    [BeforeFeature]
    private static void InitializeObjectFactories()
    {
        ObjectFactory.Initialize(x =>
        {
            x.AddRegistry<StoreRegistry>();
            x.AddRegistry<CommonRegistry>();
        });
    }   
}
```

To override the scope setting you will need to explicitly set it in the registration.
And the override needs to be below what is overridden

```
The working code looks like this:
[Binding]
public class MySpecFlowContext
{    
...
    [BeforeFeature]
    private static void InitializeObjectFactories()
    {
        ObjectFactory.Initialize(x =>
        {
            x.AddRegistry<StoreRegistry>();
            x.AddRegistry<CommonRegistry>();
            x.AddRegistry<RegistryOverrideForTest>();
        });
    }    

    class RegistryOverrideForTest : Registry
    {
        public RegistryOverrideForTest()
        {
             //NOTE: type of scope is needed when overriding the registered classes/interfaces, when leaving it empty the scope will be what was registered originally, f ex "HybridHttpOrThreadLocalScoped" in my case. 
            For<DataContext>()
                .Transient()
                .Use<DataContext>()
                .Ctor<string>("connection").Is(ConnectionBuilder.GetConnectionString());
        }
    }
}
```